# Django Rest view optimize queryset having multi level depth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-serializer

I have a view that requires data from many related objects at 3rd, 4th level relations.

Here goes the view:

```
class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Order.objects.select_related().prefetch_related().order_by('-id')
```

Now in the serializer I have to fetch the stock for a related item of this order and then perform certain calculations on it.

```
class OrderListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    shortages = SerializerMethodField()
    def get_shortages(self, obj):
        item = obj.order_line.product.item
        stock =  (
                order_line.product.item.item_instances.filter(stock_quantity__gt=0)
                .aggregate(stock=Coalesce(Sum("stock_quantity"), 0, output_field=FloatField()))
                .get("stock", 0)
            )
        required_stock = self.calculate_required_stock()
        if stock < required_stock: .....
```

In the above piece of code the line `order_line.product.item.item_instances` represents 4 models and if I populate the queryset's prefetch_related with `('order_line__product__item')` and `('order_line__product__item__item_instances')` still the queries sent to the DB are in thousand.

How can I improve this situation.

**Update Adding Example Models**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_line = models.ForeignKey(
        "OrderLine",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="orders",
    )
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, max_length=13, blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ....................

class OrderLine(models.Model):
    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(
        "SalesOrder",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="sales_order_lines",
    )
    product = models.ForeignKey("Product", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    quantities = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    ..............................

class Product(models.Model):
    design = models.ForeignKey(
        Design, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="design_products"
    )
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="item_products"
    )
    ...............................


class Item(models.Model):
    shrinkage = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    ..............................


class ItemInstance(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="item_instances"
    )
    stock_quantity = models.FloatField(
        default=0.0, blank=True, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)]
    )
```

Comment: Could you please share your models ?

Comment: Hi @Alombaros. I just updated the post and added some example models which are similar to what I have. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`prefetch_related` will populate some cache on `order_line.product.item.item_instances`. This cache will be discarded if you attempt to `.filter` or any other operation on the queryset rendering the `.prefetch_related` call useless.

You could do something like this:

```py
class SumSubquery(Subquery):
    template = (
        "(SELECT SUM(%(field_to_get_sum_from)s) FROM (%(subquery)s) "
        "as subquery)"
    )

    def __init__(self, field_to_get_sum_from, queryset, output_field):
        super().__init__(
            queryset,
            output_field,
            field_to_get_sum_from=field_to_get_sum_from,
        )

item_instance_qs = ItemInstance.objects.all()
item_instance_qs = item_instance_qs.filter(item__item_products__orderline_set__orders__id=OuterRef("pk"))
item_instance_qs = item_instance_qs.values("stock_quantity")

qs = Order.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(stock=SumSubquery("sotck_quantity", item_instance_qs, IntegerField()))


class OrderListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    shortages = SerializerMethodField()
    def get_shortages(self, obj):
        stock =  obj.stock
        required_stock = self.calculate_required_stock()
        if stock < required_stock: .....
```